# Microscopic image analysis in Matlab

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching

I am trying to analyze microscopic images (segmentation and feature extraction). I will also try to see cell pattern change over time mathematically (resource: tissue section image over three timings). I couldn't find much research work, any ideas, suggestions ?

Comment: Please add your code and image which is missing and see the tutorial for specifying question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are MANY different types of microscopic images (EM, IF, H&E, etc.) and even more staining methods. You need to share at least on image.